# I encountered an error with Apex PMD while using VS Code

Tags: sfdx-plugin, pmd

**Static Analysis Failed. Error Details: PMD Command Failed! Enable "Show StdErr" setting for more info.**

*I already enable this setting inside vs code but still getting same error*

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can see more details in the output window about the issue. Please check.

Comment: I am getting this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaR2G.png

Comment: It seems your project structure is not correct, PMD is not able to locate your Apex classes.

Comment: Please let me know what I need to do now

Comment: Ditto for me. I have used PMD for about a year. Since a week or two, I get this error every time I save a file. Show StdErr had already been turned on. No more detailed error is available. Very frustrating.

Comment: Try to raise an issue here https://github.com/ChuckJonas/vscode-apex-pmd/issues You might get an answer.